# OOP design - Process an entire sequence of Foo objects

Tags: c++, design-patterns, opencv

I'm new to objected-oriented design and I was hoping I could get some advice regarding a better way to design this project.

I have started with a FooSequence class which should initialize and store a sequence of Foo objects in a vector. I would like to be able to modify and delete the Foo objects from this sequence. That is, apply a number of algorithms to process the entire sequence of Foos, and delete poor-quality Foos from this sequence.

I'm not sure how I should interface FooSequence with a class that processes the Foo objects. If anyone could elaborate on relevant design patterns and pitfalls, I would greatly appreciate it.

I suppose I could:

a) Expand the scope of FooSequence and rename to something like FooProcessor where the member functions of FooProcessor will process member vSequence_

b) Provide accessor and mutator functions to allow read-write access to Foo objects. Use another class (FooProcessor) to modify and delete Foo objects from FooSequence. I'm not sure how this should be interfaced.

```
//A simplified header of the FooSequence class
class FooSequence {
public:
  FooSequence(const std::string &sequence_directory);
  ~FooSequence();

  //To process the sequence, another class must know the capacity of the vector
  //I'm not sure if interfacing to std::vector member functions makes much sense
  std::size_t getSize() const { return vSequence_.size(); }

  //Should I use an accessor that returns a non-const reference??
  //In this case, Why not just make the vector public?
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> getFoo;

  //Return a non-const reference to individual Foo in the sequence??
  //This doesn't help iterate over the sequence unless size of vector is known
  std::shared_ptr<Foo>& operator[] (std::size_t index) { 
  return vSequence_[index];
  }

private:
  const std::string directory_;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> vSequence_;
  FooSequence(const FooSequence &);
  void operator=(const FooSequence &);
};
```

I've tried consulting Design Patterns by the GoF but I think it is too advanced for me just yet. Any advice would be tremendously appreciated.

Edit: While I think this question should have a general answer regarding object-oriented design, I thought I should clarify that I am looking to interface an ImageSequence class with OpenCV. I am wondering about which strategies or designs I can use to best interface ImageSequence with other classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what kind of processing you need to do on your Foo objects, I believe a simple approach of just having an `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>` in conjunction with standard algorithm calls from the STL could be enough.

There is a lot you can do with the STL:

- Sort
- Transform
- Find
- Rearrange
- etc...

And all these algorithms are available to you for use on `std::vector` because the standard containers and algorithms are designed to work together.

Have a look at the list of algorithms from cppreference:

[STL alrogithm reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

**General Design Guidelines (in response to your edit)**

Keep it simple. The simpler your design is, the easier it will be to maintain your program. If your sequence of images can be represented as a simple vector, do it. You can then have other functions/classes operate on that vector by iterating over the images and processing them.

A simple ranged for works here:

```
for (auto& myImage: myImageVector) {
    // Process my image here
}
```

Comment: +1 for not reinventing the wheel, and keeping the OP out of the [Kingdom of Nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.nl/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html).

Comment: Sorry, I was embarrassed by my question so I tried to keep my post generic. I want to interface this image sequence class with opencv.

Comment: Again, it depends on what you want to do. It might be possible to do a simple ranged for loop `for (auto& foo : myFooVector) {/*call an opencv function*/ }`

Comment: @socratic for example, your Image objects could have a member function that does custom processing on themselves (e.g. blur() or whatever) and then you could iterate over all your objects with the ranged for loop mentioned in my previous comment and call blur() on them.

Comment: @KevinCadieux Thank you, Kevin. I had considered that. I was just not convinced that was the best way to go about it. I suppose I view ImageSequence as a container and that I should be able to pass an image sequence to a function (perhaps a function of another class) and perform operations on the sequence. But I don't know anything.

Comment: @socratic The thing is that vector is already a sequence so I don't see much point in adding a sequence wrapper over it just for the sake of changing its name. You could just as well pass a vector to your function/class and make that function/class go through all the images and process them. Many people when they begin OOP (including me when I began) try to overcomplicate things. The key here is to keep it simple.

Comment: @KevinCadieux I expected to hear this criticism. I think I have sufficient reason to use this class; the code I included with my question is extremely simplified. Anyway, thanks for your advice. +1

Answer (score 1):

for_each is a construct which allows you to apply a custom function to each element in the container.

For example in your case:

```
myCustomFunction ( Foo& fooObj)
{
    //do something with the foo object
}
```

now you can call

```
for_each(vSequence_.begin(),vSequence_.end(),myCustomFunction)
```

This statement will execute `myCustomFunction` for each element in the sequence.

This is not a design advice per say , but in the context of your point a , A `FooProcessor` can use `for_each` whenever batch processing is required on all the objects.

Answer (score 1):

i doubt, that you need that class at all.

in real life, you'd have a `vector<Mat>` (not a `vector<shared_ptr<Mat>>` , since Mat already acts as a smartpointer) and call it a day.